# Modify pre-exist joomla website in localhost

Tags: web, joomla

I want to modify a pre-exist Joomla website from web server in localhost. The source files are able to access in cPanel. How do I modify it in localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want a development setup where you can work while the current setup is unaffected? You can download your current database (using phpmyadmin export) and all files to your own computer, and setup everything there (the procedure will differ on different systems).

An alternative method is to setup a development environment on the existing server:

- Setup a subdomain in cpanel, pointing to another folder on your server
- Set a password for the subdomain in cpanel (to prevent unauthorized access to your dev site)
- Copy your files to the subfolder
- Export your database (with phpmyadmin)
- In the export sql-file, replace all your table prefixes (something_) with another prefix (testsomething_)
- Import the file using phpmyadmin
- Change the table profix for your installation in the subdomain
- test your site at http://subdomain.yoursite.com

Now you can quite safely develop in your subdomain without affecting the live site. You might affect the live site if there are absolute references to the live site in your code, or if you do stuff that affects the whole server, but in general this should work without problems.

Comment: Thanks. It helps me a lot.